# Bootstrap 4 Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, bootstrap-4, jquery-form-validator

I'm a beginner with bootstrap and I have seen a lot of bootstrap 3 form validation plugins etc, but I haven't found any for bootstrap 4.

I'm trying to validate multiple forms, and here is my code:

```html
<!-- Contact -->
<div class="container white">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container white percent100">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="padder-t2">
          <h1>Contact</h1>
          <div class="horiz-divider"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row padder-t padder-b">
    <div class="container white">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- Form -->
        <form class="form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form">
          <fieldset>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  <label class="control-label pull-right"><h4>First Name</h4></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 inputGroupContainer">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  <label class="control-label pull-right"><h4>Last Name</h4></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 inputGroupContainer">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  <label class="control-label pull-right"><h4>E-Mail</h4></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 inputGroupContainer">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="email">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  <label class="control-label pull-right"><h4>Phone #</h4></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 inputGroupContainer">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                    <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" type="text">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text area -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  <label class="control-label pull-right"><h4>Message</h4></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-5 inputGroupContainer">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                    <textarea id="comment" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Success message -->
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger raised">Send <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row padder-b">
    <div class="row col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
      <h4 class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">Contact us directly:</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
      <h4 class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 padder-lr">Mail:</h4>
      <a class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 padder-lr" href="mailto:lorem@ipsum.com">
        <h4 id="mail">lorem@ipsum.com</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
      <h4 class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 padder-lr">Adress:</h4>
      <h4 class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 padder-lr" id="adress">2 LoremIpsum Road, 67000 City - Country</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to modify existing js, but I had no luck.

Here is the rendered form:

[jsfiddle of the form](https://jsfiddle.net/ytwsp6uo/1/)

Comment: You can read this part for bootstrap;
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation

then, you can get an idea.

Comment: Styling is one thing, but I would be interested in a solid solution that is officially compatible with validating bootstrap 4 forms as well.

Comment: See this question for the latest Bootstrap 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938703/cant-make-the-validation-work-in-bootstrap-4/45938912#45938912

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First I solved my issue with an external library like [Jonathan Dion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795341/jonathan-dion) suggested. But recently I came across this :

**Bootstrap v4.0** introduced their own form validation that you can still pair with backend php validation. From the [Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation) :

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Doesn't look good!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then using JS :

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

This provides input border colorating and displays the valid / invalid feedback blocks according to the given pattern or properties. It is applied via CSS’s two pseudo-classes, `:invalid` and `:valid`. It applies to `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to change my form tag.  From <form id="needs-validation" novalidate asp-action="ItemSubmissionForm" asp-controller="ItemSubmission" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">     To   <form id="needs-validation" novalidate  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  essentially removing the controller and action atttribute.

Answer (score 9):

**Update 2020** - Bootstrap 4.4.x

Here's another option (modern JS) if you want to validate each input one at a time (**live** or **real-time**) instead of waiting for the entire form to be submitted...

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // fetch all the forms we want to apply custom style
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')

    // loop over each input and watch blur event
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(inputs, function(input) {

      input.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
        // reset
        input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
        input.classList.remove('is-valid')

        if (input.checkValidity() === false) {
            input.classList.add('is-invalid')
        }
        else {
            input.classList.add('is-valid')
        }
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})()

<form class="container" novalidate="" action="/echo" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="input1">Enter some input</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input1" id="input1" 
            autocomplete="no" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">No, you missed this one.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="input2">Enter password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}$" 
            autocomplete="no" name="input2" id="input2">
        <div class="valid-feedback">Nice! You got this one!</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">At least 6 chars: 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase and numeric</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

https://codeply.com/p/mzBNbAlOvQ

Comment: this method ignores minlength and maxlength

Comment: Did the question mention min and max?

Comment: also does not replace full form validation at submission. with novalidate all html5 input validations are disabled (required, pattern, min/max), it essentially does nothing to prevent submitting an empty form, does not even have a disabled button, must be used/paired with the answer below to be decent (onsubmit on the form)

Answer (score 4):

**You can use any library available on the web.** You may try [jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). It's pretty easy to use, just read the documentation.

Add the `required` attribute on your `input` and jqueryvalidation will do the job. For styling, you can add your own CSS and make it look like bootstrap.

Hopes it help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#contact_form').validate()
})
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/jha6b2zt/1/)

Comment: that's what I tried but it doesn't work well with my layout, it adds the message right after my input and I don't now how to force add under the form-group...

Comment: Your example doesn't work on submit if you only place the name in.

Comment: You just need to add `required` on the input.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simpler and a bit more modern way to implement [Bootstrap 4 JS Form validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation):

**Note**: Keep in mind that each `<form>` element must have the `novalidate` attribute and at the same time, each `<input>` element in it must have the `required` attribute.

```js
// Upon load..
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  // Grab all the forms
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
  
  // Iterate over each one
  for (let form of forms) {
  
    // Add a 'submit' event listener on each one
    form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
    
      // check if the form input elements have the 'required' attribute  
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Bootstrap will handle incomplete form fields');
      } else {
        // Since form is now valid, prevent default behavior..
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.info('All form fields are now valid...');
      }
      
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
      
    });
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!-- Load necessary libraries -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add form -->
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 40px;">
  <form class="student-search needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
        <label for="input-name-search" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-name-search" placeholder="Name" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter a name please.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <button id="btn-search" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Search student</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the reason my code wasn't validating: I didn't have a submit button to trigger the validation. Make sure to have it.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

Comment: Heads up guys, a submit button is not "required" to validate a form field.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need for a library here, you can use the native `reportValidation()` method: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity). You can call it on individual inputs or on the entire form itself.