# Can't make the validation work in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to implement [validation by Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation) and I've pasted the following sample on my page:

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-success" id="inputSuccess1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
```

I can see that the appearance of the input control has changed (it's a bit rounded and much more aesthetic now) **but** it still doesn't show the green border as can be seen on the page linked to. The Bootstrap I'm linking to is pointed out as follows.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I have tried to google for this issue but to no avail. I have [a fiddle illustrating the issue](//jsfiddle.net/Chamster/ecqoxsez/embed/).

What can I do about it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (Update 2021)**

Since jQuery is no longer required for Bootstrap 5, it's easy to do client-side validation with vanilla JavaScript. The docs include a generic code example that should work on all forms with `needs-validation`..

```
(function () {
    'use strict'

    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
        .forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
            }

            form.classList.add('was-validated')
        }, false)
        })
})()
```

[Bootstrap 5 Form Validation Demo](https://codeply.com/p/xLaQQsUzpY)

**Bootstrap 4 (Original Answer)**

Validation has changed as of the [Bootstrap 4 beta release](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation).

The valid state selectors use the `was-validated` class which would be added dynamically after validating the form via **client-side** JavaScript. For example...

```
<form class="container was-validated" novalidate="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i1" id="inputSuccess1">
        <div class="valid-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess2">Input with danger</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i2" required="" id="inputSuccess2">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">That didn't work.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Text</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

https://codeply.com/go/45rU7UOhFo

[Form Validation Example Demo - Bootstrap 4.0.0](https://codeply.com/go/oPUDdgN6CK/bootstrap-4-validation)

---

As explained in the docs, if you intend to use **server-side** validation you can simply set the **`is-valid`** or **`is-invalid`** classes on the form-controls...

```
<form class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" id="inputSuccess1">
        <div class="valid-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: hello,I'm browsing[bootstrap's validation docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#validation)and I couldn´t make client-side validation work,until I noticed (inspector) there is a script in that docs page,which is the one making it work,I mean aside from the cores bootstrap.js and jquery.js,indeed when I added it to my project,it worked.Is that actually the way?do I actually need to manually add that chunk of code,cause I´m telling you,it won´t work without it,not in my project,nor in the docs.I can´t post the script here but it´s in the docs I linked,right after the form tag

Comment: Can’t believe how hard this was to find.  The docs don’t make clear at all that you need a small event handler to add the class («you may choose when to activate them (typically after form submission is attempted)»).

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: How to combine both client side and server side without having replace was-validate?

Comment: why not give a link to the css file?

Comment: @pajarnas -- what CSS file?

Answer (score 17):

It appears the validation changes again in the final release version of Bootstrap 4: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation.

It becomes more complicated than I thought.

Custom style client side validation is recommended:

1. When validated, the form adds a class named `was-validated`.
2. Feedback messages are wrapped within `.valid-feedback` or `.invalid-feedback`.

For server-side validation:

1. No need for `was-validated` class on the `<form>` tag.
2. Add `.is-valid` or `.is-invalid` on the input control.
3. Add `.invalid-feedback` or `.valid-feedback` for the feedback message.

Comment: I don't think the form needs to have needs-validation class, this is just on the bootstrap doc but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Saying "No need for `was-validated`" isn't really sufficient.  I'd say, "do not add `was-validated` if you want the server-side validation to work... You can't use both together.  Either you use client-side with `was-validated` or you use `is-invalid`/`is-valid` by adding it from server side code.

Comment: Note that as per [example code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/?#custom-styles) in the document (scroll to the bottom of the code blob) the client-side Javascript needs to add the `was-validated` class upon form submission! Otherwise, nothing will show!

Answer (score 0):

my simple way....

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="unombre" 
placeholder="su nombre"  name="vnombre" required 
onblur="valida(this.id)">

<script>
function valida(v) {
var dato = document.getElementById(v).value
document.getElementById(v).className +=' is-valid';
}
</script>
```