# CI4: Validation on Modal before inserting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, codeigniter-4

I'm currently having a problem with my modal. It still proceed with the submit function even if the input field is empty. The required function in the input field seems to be not working. How can I validate the input field first before submitting?

Here's my code for modal in the View

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="Ad_ModSY">
   <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="" data-async data-target="#AddFormDialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title">SCHOOL YEAR</h5>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                     <label>From</label>
                     <input type="number" class="form-control" name="a_year_from" id="a_year_from" required>
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please input the Start of School Year.
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                     <label>To</label>
                     <input type="number" class="form-control" name="a_year_to" id="a_year_to" required>
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please input the End of School Year.
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label>School Term</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="School Term" name="a_sy_term" id="a_sy_term" required>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                     Please input the School Year.
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer bg-whitesmoke br">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Close</button>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add-sy"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Here's my script for AJAX.

```
$(".add-sy").click(function(){

      var a_year_from = $('#a_year_from').val();
      var a_year_to = $('#a_year_to').val();

      let year = a_year_from.concat("-",a_year_to.toString());

      var data = {
        'year': year,
        'sy_term': $('#a_sy_term').val(),
      }

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>Add-School-Year",
        data: data,
        success: function(response){

          $('#Ad_ModSY').modal('hide');
          location.reload();

        }
      });

    });
```

Here's the code for the Controller

```
public function SY_Add()
    {

        $model = new Mod_SY();
        $data = [
            'year' => $this->request->getPost('year'),
            'sy_term' => $this->request->getPost('sy_term')
        ];


        $model->save($data);

        $_SESSION['message'] =
        '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible show fade">
          <div class="alert-body">
              <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                <span>&times;</span>
              </button>
              Data has been added!
          </div>
        </div>';

        session()->markAsFlashdata("message");
        return $this->response->setJSON($data);


    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't make the validation work in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938703/cant-make-the-validation-work-in-bootstrap)

Comment: You're missing the JavaScript source code meant to *disable form submissions if there are invalid fields*. [Custom styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/?#custom-styles)